# Word: remove page from multipage userform

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want, depending of the previous choice from the user just let some tab's being seen.

Once i am new in VBA, i start showing all the tab's and after the choice from the user, i remove the tab's that i don't want. For that i am using this line of code

`MultiPage1.Pages.Remove "name of the tab"`

The problem is, if i don't have the same CAPTION and the NAME field of the tab the tab is not remove.

If anyone have a diferent solution for this or another away to remove without have to change the caption for the same name of NAME field i would be thankful.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the Page number as well to remove it for example `MultiPage1.Pages.Remove 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can give a page of a multi-page control a different name from the caption in the Properties Window. You can access it from the View menu.

[image: Screenshot of Properties Window]

I've highlighed the name of the control in yellow and the caption in aqua.

Comment: I know that, my problem is beacause i have different Name and caption.For example if i have the name "kp1" and the caption "kp-1" when i try to remove the code above the tab is not removed.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the issue. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If the captions are unique, you could use a Select Case statement to get the name, based on the caption. Are users actually typing in the caption of the tabs they want, or selecting from check boxes? In either case, the captions would have to be unique, so you could do something like:

```
Select Case True
   Case Check1.Value
      MultiPage1.Pages.Remove Pages("kp").Index

   Case Check2.Value
      MultiPage1.Pages.Remove Pages("jp").Index
End Select
```

That's a bit rough, but is that the general idea?

Comment: The caption are unique. the only diference from my code to yours is that i use the stamment IF. i try to remove as you said but an error  at this part "Pages("kp").PageIndex", he says sub or function not defined. why you that is a bit rough? thanks

Comment: Sorry, rough because I was having trouble accessing Intellisense. It should just be Index, not PageIndex. I've edited. IF statement would work as well; the main point is that you need code that ties the captions (or the caption selectors) to the page name or index. I think it's easier to work with the names and derive the index, but YMMV.